# Swift - Black Bottom Bar when Pushing to a New ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I got this when I push to a new View Controller:

[image: image of the problem]

In the storyboard, I did not set the hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to true.
In the "More" view as shown in the image above, I had this, in which the `PostsController` is the "Like" view in the image:

```
let destinationVC = segue.destination as! PostsController
destinationVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
```

And also, there is a bottom tabbar in the "More" view.

What should I do to remove this black space?
Thanks!

Comment: is this problem only in iPhone X device .?

Answer (score 0):

you can put this in your PostsController instead of doing it in segue

```
override var hidesBottomBarWhenPushed: Bool {
    get {
        return true
    }
    set {
        self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. And also in the PostsController, I need to use `if` to check if it is that type of PostsController. If it is page `Likes`, then I hide it. Otherwise, I do not.